# SQL query to ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How to convert this into an active record query?

```
select quantity from carts where cart_id = ? and product_id = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cart.select(:quantity).where(:cart_id => cart_id, :product_id => product_id)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error "can't convert Fixnum into Array"
I was trying to do this:

"qty = CartItem.select(:quantity).where(:cart_id => kart.id, :product_id => product.id)

"CartItem.where("cart_id = ? AND product_id = ?", kart.id, product.id).first.update_column(:quantity, qty+1)"

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested only in the value, and not the overhead of the object (so you're not interested in any of the Cart methods, associations etc), then pluck is available and a little better performing:

```
Cart.pluck(:quantity).where(:cart_id => cart_id, :product_id => product_id)
```